# QGIS using Spatial bookmarks in Layout Manager

Tags: qgis, layouts, bookmarks

I work with spatial bookmarks on a regular basis, and wondered if there's a way to use them to set the "map extents" in the layout manager in QGIS. At the moment I'm typing/copying them manually, while in most raster and vector processing tools I can load the project bookmarks in as computational boundary very easily.

I'm looking for a time saver here, not a new functionality. I'm just bored of copy/pasting coordinates from and to four separate fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(QGIS 3.34)

In the *Item Properties* pane of the *Map* item there is a button to assign a Spatial Bookmark

[image]

Comment: I never saw that! I was looking at the drop down next to the extents field!

Comment: It is a little hidden indeed. Perhaps it would be handy to have the relevant buttons from that toolbar in  the Extents section also